# Permission Denial: runUninstall from pm command asks to run as user -1 but is calling from user 0;

Tags: android, debugging, permissions, adb, samsung-knox

I'm just upgrade my Android device (Samsung J7Pro) to 9.0 (Pie) and when I want to run any application from Android Studio I face to this problem that says:

> Permission Denial: runUninstall from pm command asks to run as user -1
>   but is calling from user 0; this requires
>   android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL.

I have tried to add

```
INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
```

to my AndroidManifest.xml but get the same error.

Any help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found the solution

1. First turn off the developers option
2. Restart your device
3. Turn on again your developers option and turn on Usb Debugging

Answer (score 0):

For the solution you have to try two things

1. try to add the this permission in your android manifest file.
   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES"
   run the app and it will work
2. if the above work didn't help try the following step:
3. Uninstall the app.
4. Disable the Developer option from setting
5. Restart the Device
6. Enable the Developer option from setting-->About phone-->Software Information and click seven time on Build Number.
7. Now from Developer option(Below About Phone) Enable Use Debugging.
8. Run the app and i believe it should work.