# Why upgrading to Flutter 1.7 cause error?

Tags: flutter, dart

I upgraded my flutter from `1.5.4-hotfix.2` to `1.7.8+hotfix.3` which report an error during the build.

The error reported was first experience on my current app.  I then decided to create a new app (the default flutter app).  I compiled it and got the same error.  I added the requesting permission to the android manifest, but it did not work.  For context it works fine on ios by the way.

This is the output with the error:

> Launching lib/main.dart on SM J701M in debug mode...   Built
>   build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
>
> Security exception: Permission Denial: forceStopPackage() from
>   pid=10286, uid=2000 requires android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES
>
> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: forceStopPackage()
>   from pid=10286, uid=2000 requires
>   android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES
>
> at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.forceStopPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:8748)
>
> at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.runForceStop(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:967)
>
> at 
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.onCommand(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:197)
>
> at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103)
>
> at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onShellCommand(ActivityManagerService.java:20320)
>
> at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:642)
>
> at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:540)
>
> at
>   android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:3442)
>
> at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:4181)
>
> at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:739)
>
> Error: ADB exited with exit code 1 Performing Streamed Install
>
> adb: failed to install
>   /Users/wilfordmorrison/testnew/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk:
>
> Security exception: Permission Denial: runInstallCreate from pm
>   command asks to run as user -1 but is calling from user 0;  this
>   requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
>
> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: runInstallCreate from
>   pm command asks to run as user -1 but is calling from user 0; this
>   requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
>
> at
>   com.android.server.am.UserController.handleIncomingUser(UserController.java:1827)
>
> at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:25069)
>
> at
>   android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:4848)
>
> at
>   com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.translateUserId(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2402)
>
> at
>   com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doCreateSession(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2408)
>
> at
>   com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:907)
>
> at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(Pa
>
> Error launching application on SM J701M.
>
> Exited (sigterm)

Regards,

Will

Comment: Edit: Did you add both permissions in AndroidManifest.xml? android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES and  android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

Comment: I noted that in the submission.  Adding these permissions in the android manifest file  did not fix it.

Comment: Upon testing and checking, the error above is not connected to the flutter version upgrade.  The issue is the device.  Samsung send out an update to my phone around the same time when I upgraded the flutter version.  I have another device and the app works fine on it.  Currently trying to find out what is causing the adb to fail.  Will update once I fix it.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the update. U can try on multiple android simulators to confirm if its working fine. But yea it sux that now u cant use your samsung device to test.

Comment: dont think its because flutter version upgrade, i'm still using 1.5.4 hotfix 2 and got the exactly same error when i run it on my samsung android device that just upgraded to a new version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

1. First turn off the developers option
2. Restart your device
3. Turn on again your developers option and turn on Usb Debugging

found it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56723254/permission-denial-rununinstall-from-pm-command-asks-to-run-as-user-1-but-is-ca).